# 22.04.4 Desktop not installing

Tags: laptop

I am trying to install 22.04.4 Desktop on my Panasonic CF-20 Toughbook. I get to what I think is the desktop screen and that is it. I see the date, time, volume and battery icon. I dose not give me the option to try or install box. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get to the Desktop? Do you see a screen before that that says "Install or Try Ubuntu". If  you do see it press `Install` and not `Try`.

Comment: Can you try again and take a picture at each step? Then add the pictures with a line of text describing what you did at each step [to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507510/edit).